# $\int_\Omega\liminf_{h\rightarrow\infty}k\vert f_h\vert^p$, where $\{f_h\}_{h\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges in $ L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

I have a problem in which I have to prove l.s.c. of a certain functional. After a couple of inequalities I still have to show $$\int_\Omega\liminf_{h\rightarrow\infty}\ \  k\vert f_h\vert^p dx=\int_\Omega k\vert f\vert^p dx,$$
where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, k is a constant in $\mathbb{R}$,  $\ f\in L^p(\Omega)$ and $\ \{f_h\}_{h\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $L^p(\Omega)$ which converges to $f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$. I know that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence almost everywhere of a subsequence, which means $\exists\  f_{h_{j}}$, s.t. $f_{h_{j}}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for almost every x in $\Omega$, but I'm not sure how to combine this information with the $\liminf$. I have to admit that I'm not sure about the equality, for my purpouse it's enough the inequality $\geq$. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: On $[0,1]$ consider the sequence

$$1-\chi_{[0,1/2]},\, 1-\chi_{[1/2,1]},
1-\chi_{[0,1/3]},\,1-\chi_{[1/3,2/3]},\,1-\chi_{[2/3,1]},\,\dots$$

Comment: I can see that the sequence is not pointwise convergent, and it converges in $L^p$ to $\chi_{[0,1]}$. The $\inf$ of every element of the sequence should be zero, thus also the $\liminf$ should be zero. This seems to be a counterexample to what I was trying to prove. I think I made some mistake in one of my previous steps. Thanks.